Синонимизировать метки [quasar-framework] и [quasar.js]
Синонимизировать:
quasar-framework - 19 вопросов (есть описание)
quasar.js - 13 вопросов (нет описания)
Основная метка - quasar-framework - по аналогии c stackoverflow.com

Готово!
updating post history, 13 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 13 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 6 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'quasar.js': [quasar.js] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records for type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 25
tag remapping of [quasar-framework] and [quasar.js] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
3 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym quasar.js -> quasar-framework was approved!

